# How to style image size inside DataGrid cell template?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding, datatemplate

I need to make all images inside my DataGrid the same size. Images are inside items cell templates, in many places. How to apply size style to all of them?

UPD code sample:

```
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Image Source="Resources/Image1.png"/>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                        // some other columns with text or images
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

Comment: if you could provide template or binding information  you are using it will be easier for everyone to understand what you mean. **I mean post some code**.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a style with a TargetType of Image to control your sizes and then apply to all your images.

The following goes in your resource dictionary

```
    <Style x:Key="smallImageStyleKey" TargetType="Image"> 
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="32" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="32" />
    </Style>
```

Then modify the XAML for your images to look like

```
<Image Source="Resources/Image1.png" Style="{StaticResource smallImageStyleKey}"/>
```

Personally I would put each of the images in a `ViewBox` and apply the style to that though.

Ideally you should resize all of your images in a proper image editing program first though as that will do a much better job of resizing your images than sizing them in WPF will do though.

Comment: Why it doesn't work when I specify style for Image target type without key?